# C++ Global variable declaration

Tags: c++, variables, global-variables

What I want to do is just to define a variable in a header file and use it on two different cpp files without redefinition that variable each time I include that header
Here is how I tried :

Variables.h

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H // header guards
#define VARIABLES_H

static bool bShouldRegister;

#endif
```

(I also tried extern but nothing changed)

And in a cpp file I give it a value `::bShouldRegister = true` or `bShouldRegister = true;`

In my another cpp file I check it's value by creating a thread and check its value in a loop (and yes my thread function works well)

```
 while (true)
 {
     if (::bShouldRegister) // Or if (bShouldRegister)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"Value Changed","Done",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
  Sleep(100);
 }
```

And yes, that MessageBox never appears (bShouldRegister never gets true :/)

Comment: [C++ FAQ 27.15: What's a good coding standard for using global variables?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/global-vars.html)

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov the information you linked is currently dead. Is it the same as [What's a good coding standard for using global variables?, C++ FAQ](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/global-vars.html)?

Comment: @Wolf, yes, that used to be the FAQ mirror

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You should use `extern` otherwise you will have separated `bShouldRegister` variables in each translation unit with probably different values.

Put this in a header file (.h):

```
extern bool bShouldRegister;
```

Put this in one of implementation files (.cpp):

```
bool bShouldRegister;
```

---

Another way which is simpler is to use `inline` keyword. Put you variable in a header file as below:

```
inline bool bShouldRegister;
```

Comment: As I said I did as you say, but nothing changed

Comment: So, your code doesn't show how you're using this global value. But the obvious thing is you should use `extern`.

Comment: I should include my header file in both cpp files, right ? if yes I'm doing this already

Comment: You can include the header file everywhere you want. but you should not include the cpp file anywhere. Notice, you should just have one definition for `bShouldRegister` just in a single cpp file.

Comment: @Shahriyar Did you remove "static bool bShouldRegister;" from the header and change it to "extern bool bShouldRegister;"?

Answer (score 32):

If you can use C++17, consider using an inline variable:

```
// in a header file
inline bool bShouldRegister = true;
```

See [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work) for more information.

Comment: this is really a life saver... really annoying to use `extern` in 2019

Answer (score 22):

A more [C++-like way](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#global-vars) would be using a class member, syntactically indicated by the `static` keyword. Class member variables have implicit `external` linkage.

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

class RegUtil {
public:

    static bool bShouldRegister;

};

#endif
```

in one of your cpp files (maybe `variables.cpp`), you have to define this class member:

```
#include "variables.h"

bool RegUtil::bShouldRegister;
```

Comment: imho this is almost more java-like than c++like, i would rather put it inside a namespace and drop the class

Comment: @user463035818 Both options make sense, but I think classes tend to provide narrower contexts than namespaces. I generally try to *avoid* exposing "naked" simple variables, especially bools. PS: yes you're right: I learned about static member variables from Java, but it's also a reasonable option in C++ (I never used Java for production code).

Answer (score 11):

You need to define the variable in one of the modules:

```
bool bShouldRegister;
```

Then declare it `extern` (not `static`!) in the header:

```
extern bool bShouldRegister;
```

Answer (score -3):

Here you need to define bool bShouldRegister in one class. Your header file should like this.

```
 #ifndef VARIABLES_H // header guards
#define VARIABLES_H

class abc{

public:
      bool bShouldRegister;
      abc();
#endif
```

Now initialize **bShouldRegister** variable in cpp file in constructor of abc class and then use this variable in your second cpp file using object of class. You will get your message box.

Comment: Please have another look on your "answer", it's **syntactically wrong**.

Comment: *initialize bShouldRegister variable in cpp file in constructor of abc class* -- this is a **bad advice** for static members.