# Getting linker error with header file and function definition file

Tags: c++

I’m getting this huge linker error whenever I try to run these files.

I have a setup of my main code (`main.cpp`), my header file (`Functions.hpp`) and my function definition file (`Functions.cpp`).

I have made sure that both my `main.cpp` and `Functions.cpp` both have the `#include "Functions.hpp"` at the top.

Main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Functions.hpp"
int main() {
  std::cout << "Would you like to sign up? (y/n): ";
  std::cin >> signuptrue;  
  if (signuptrue == "y" || signuptrue == "Y" || signuptrue == "Yes" || signuptrue == "yes") {
    IsSignUp = true;
  } else if (signuptrue == "n" || signuptrue == "N" || signuptrue == "No" || signuptrue == "no") {
    IsSignUp = false;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Invalid entry\n";
  }
  if (IsSignUp) {
    signup();
  }   
  goodLogin = login();
  if (goodLogin) {
    std::cout << "You are logged in\n";
    mainMenu();
  } else {
    std::cout << "You are not logged in, please try again.";
  }
}
```

Functions.hpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void signup();
bool login();
void mainMenu();
int findGold();
int updateGold(int newgold);
std::string SignUpUsername;
std::string SignUpPassword;
std::string Entered_username;
std::string Entered_password;
std::string Entered_login;
std::string signuptrue;
bool goodLogin = false;
bool IsSignUp = false;
int gold;
int newgold = 0;
int action = 0;
std::hash<std::string> hasher;
std::size_t hashedInput
```

Functions.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Functions.hpp"

void signup() {
  std::string EnteredLogin;
  std::cout << "Enter a username: ";
  std::cin >> SignUpUsername;
  std::cout << "Enter a password: ";
  std::cin >> SignUpPassword;
  std::cout << "You have signed up successfully\n";
  std::string combinedInput = SignUpUsername + SignUpPassword;
  std::size_t hashedInput = hasher(combinedInput);
  std::fstream accountFile;
  accountFile.open ("accounts.txt", std::ios::app);
  accountFile << hashedInput << '\n';
  accountFile.close();
}

bool login() {
  std::string line;
  std::cout << "Enter your username: ";
  std::cin >> Entered_username;
  std::cout << "Enter your password: ";
  std::cin >> Entered_password;
  std::string combinedInput = Entered_username + Entered_password;
  hashedInput = hasher(combinedInput);
  std::ifstream accountFile;
  accountFile.open("accounts.txt");
  while (getline(accountFile, line)) {
    std::size_t hashedFileInput = std::stoul(line);
    if (hashedInput == hashedFileInput) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

int findGold() {
  std::ifstream accountFile("accounts.txt");
  std::string line, goldAmountStr;
  while (getline(accountFile, line)) {
    if (line == std::to_string(hashedInput)) {
      std::getline(accountFile, goldAmountStr);
      try {
        int goldAmount = std::stoi(goldAmountStr);
        return goldAmount;
      } catch(const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  accountFile.close();
  return 0;
}

int updateGold(int newGold) {
  std::ifstream inFile("accounts.txt");
  std::ofstream outFile("temp.txt");
  std::string line, goldAmountStr;
  while (std::getline(inFile, line)) {
    if (line == std::to_string(hashedInput)) {
      std::getline(inFile, goldAmountStr);
      outFile << line << '\n' << newGold << '\n'; 
    } else {
      outFile << line << '\n';
    }
  }
  inFile.close();
  outFile.close();
  std::remove("accounts.txt");
  std::rename("temp.txt", "accounts.txt");
  return newGold;
}

void mainMenu() {
  gold = findGold();
  int ne;
  std::cin >> ne;
  gold = updateGold(ne);
  std::cout << "you have " << gold << " gold";
}
```

I was researching on this and all it said was to make sure that I have included the header file in both the `main.cpp` and `functions.cpp` file.

I have done that but I still get the huge linker error.

```bash
g++ main.cpp Functions.hpp Functions.cpp
```

```
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0xc0): multiple definition of `SignUpUsername[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0xc0): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0xa0): multiple definition of `SignUpPassword[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0xa0): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x80): multiple definition of `Entered_username[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x80): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x60): multiple definition of `Entered_password[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x60): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `hashedInput'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x14): multiple definition of `gold'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x14): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x40): multiple definition of `Entered_login[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x40): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `signuptrue[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `hasher[abi:cxx11]'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0xc): multiple definition of `action'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0xc): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `newgold'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `IsSignUp'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/ccA63Jrg.o:(.bss+0x19): multiple definition of `goodLogin'; /tmp/ccpCKPCg.o:(.bss+0x19): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You forgot to show the error.  Please also include the command(s) you use to compile and link.

Comment: do you link functions.o and main.o?

Comment: Show how you are building this code. I expect you are not building both source files. If you are using VSCode you did not follow the official directions which tell you that by default it builds only the active file and gives you the change you need to make to tasks.json to build all source files in your folder.

Comment: ***all it said was to make sure that I have included the header file in both the main.cpp and functions.cpp file*** That is very wrong advice. Forgetting to include a required header would normally cause a compiler error not a linker error.

Comment: I’m just running it through riplit and the consol gives me this error at the end Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: ***I’m just running it through riplit*** Figure out how to get it show the build command executed and the exact text of the error. Both of these are necessary for help.

Comment: All of those global variables defined in the `Functions.hpp` could cause multiple defined symbols.

Comment: I wasn’t able to figure out how it was building it, so I went into the shell and did g++ main.cpp Functions.hpp Functions.cpp and it returned the linker error. I don’t have enough characters in a comment though to show the error

Comment: Copy and paste the exact text of the error message to your question. This is a requirement of the site.

Comment: It does look like it is talking about multiple definitions of variables

Comment: Most likely the problem is this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929681/c-global-variable-declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929681/c-global-variable-declaration)

Comment: I fixed it, I just had to add inline to all the variables in the hpp file

Comment: @Voyager That will fix it, but perhaps you do not understand the basic issue. Read the linked duplicate and make sure you understand the difference between a declaration and a definition. You got into trouble because you put global variable definitions in a header file when you should have put global variable declarations in that header file, the corresponding definitions should be placed in one of your cpp files.

Comment: My advice is to avoid global variables in the first place.

Comment: Making a diagnostic message go away doesn't necessarily fix the mistake. Sometimes it makes things worse by preventing the compiler from delivering an important diagnostic. Be very sure that `inline` produces the program behaviour you need and didn't merely transform the problem form an obvious build-time error into a logic mistake you need to debug.